# .NET: Saving Clipboard Image to PNG fails

Tags: .net, png, clipboard, paint, jpeg

I have a weird issue with saving of clipboard image to png. When taking a screenshot with prtscr or snipping tool it works fine with Clipboard.GetImage() and PngBitmapEncoder. But when copying the image from Paint and doing the same I get a empty image as result. At least it looks empty when trying to view it, though it seems to contain valid PNG-image-data. When using the Jpeg-encoder it works fine. Whats the problem with PNG and Paint? Does it have anything to do with transparency?

**Update**
to clarify: Im extracting an image successfully from the clipboard. I just cant save it to disc using the PNGEncoder if the image was copied from Paint in the first place. I can save paint-clipboard-images with the JpegEncoder though... but I want to use PNG.

```
BitmapSource source = Clipboard.GetImage();
PngBitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
enc.Save(stream);
```

Above code produces a image-file with invisible content, turns up completely black or white depending on the viewer (when copied from, ctrl-c, from Paint). Which leads me to think it has something to do with transparency...

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem looks very similar to the one I described [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/)... the solution I suggested should probably work for you.

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I used your ImageFromClipboardDib and it works great! I tried CopyPixels and resetting the alpha-channel myself but whout success. The data from copypixels was only white (255). But your code did the trick!

Comment: Same here. Couldn't figure out why images copied form MSPaint were empty. Thomas' code did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try something like [ClipSpy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/clipboard/clipspy.aspx) to examine which application puts which type of content on the clipboard.